# access child component from parent component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Child and parent component are created in separate files. I am trying to access child component from parent component. But not defined error is coming.
    On other hand, if child and parent component created in single file. Then it's working correctly.

```
var Avatar = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PagePic />

      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

[CODE](https://plnkr.co/edit/KqGgiSIRprGz42qDmrUs?p=preview)

Comment: Are importing `PagePic` component in `Avatar` file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import and export `PagePic` component

**Tutorial1.js**

```
var PagePic = require('./tutorial2');
var Avatar = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PagePic />

      </div>
    );
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <Avatar />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

**Tutorial2.js**

```
var PagePic = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <h2> Inside Page Epic</h2>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = PagePic;
```

**[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/3dAjZ4D2ZkP7aOB9XYg9?p=preview)**

Comment: @adi are you using any bundle tools like webpack or browserify, because from what I can think of you need to import react in to your components.